# Callback to move V93K .tf file to another directory?

Tags: origen-sdk

Currently the Origen test program generator creates sub-directories beneath where the output dir is configured:

```
mbist/
|-- origen
|   |-- mbist_flow.rb
|   |-- mbist_params.rb
|   |-- testflow
|   |   |-- mfh.testflow.group
|   |   |   `-- Flow_mbist.tf
```

We need to move the generated V93K .tf file up 2 directories so another tool can find it.  I checked the [callbacks docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/misc/callbacks/) and none of them looked like they would work, as I believe the file handle would still be open.  Is there a way to do this with callbacks or pass an option for the generate command not to create the sub-directories...rake?

thx

** EDIT ***

Here is the working code as per Ginty:

```
def write_files(options = {})
  super
  Dir.glob("#{Origen.top_level.test_modules(default_test_module).output_dir}/testflow/mfh.testflow.group/Flow*.tf").each do |f|
    Origen.log.info("Moving #{f.split('/')[-1]} to #{Origen.top_level.test_modules(default_test_module).output_dir}/#{f}")
    FileUtils.mv f, Origen.top_level.test_modules(default_test_module).output_dir
  end
  FileUtils.rm_rf "#{Origen.top_level.test_modules(default_test_module).output_dir}/testflow"
  Origen.log.info("Deleted #{Origen.top_level.test_modules(default_test_module).output_dir}/testflow")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is hardcoded for now, though ultimately I would like to see it be made configurable via the tester object - https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/flow.rb#L17

In the meantime, an alternative approach could be to override this method in your interface: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/master/lib/origen_testers/interface.rb#L156

```
def write_files(options = {})
  super
  # Move stuff around here
end
```

Also, not everything needs to be done via a callback. In my applications, the way I normally handle this kind of thing is by making an `origen build` command within my application.

That is essentially just a script which invokes the necessary Origen commands to build the program, e.g...

```
system("origen p #{Origen.root!}/program/full.list -o #{dist_dir}/device --list #{Origen.target.name}.list")
```

Then after that you can easily add additional code to move things about to create your particular delivery package structure.